# name 'generateRandom' is not defined"

Tags: python, numpy, object, self, nameerror

I'm trying to run this code but I'm getting an error msg ---> "NameError: name 'generateRandom' is not defined"

Can anyone help me please?

```
`import numpy as np

class Mul:
    def __init__ (self,ra_result=None,rb_result=None):
        self.ra_result = ra_result
        self.rb_result = rb_result
        
    def generateRandom():
        return np.random.randint(0,2**32), np.random.randint(0,2**32)
    
    def Multi_test(self):
        self.ra_result,self.rb_result= generateRandom()
        print("expected_output (python) = ")
        print("ra=",self.ra_result,"rb=",self.rb_result," (ra*rb)=")
        return self.ra_result*self.rb_result
        
object = Mul()
object.Multi_test()`
```

Answer (score 0):

The function you're trying to call, is itself a class function, I.E. it needs to be called like this:

```
self.generateRandom()
```

Edit:
You could make the generateRandom() an internal private function, by changing it to

```
def __generateRandom(self):
...
rng = self.__generateRandom()
```

In this case you can easily access it and it's still out of reach

Comment: Leading two underscores does not mean _private_ like in other languages. You can still access the function/method/attribute. If you want to declare something for internal use then use one single underscore.

Comment: By having two underscores as the initial characters of a class function name, then you can't access that specific function outside the class

Comment: Of course you can. The name is mangled (that's what the two leading underscores are for), but the rules for the name mangling are known and you can access the data. Two leading underscores are seldom used (except by beginners maybe) and if they are used it's mostly in the context of subclassing to prevent an accidental overwrite. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers): "For example, the identifier `__spam` occurring in a class named `Ham` will be transformed to `_Ham__spam`."

Comment: I was not aware of this. Thanks for enlightening me! I thought it to private in the sense that it was un-callable from outside the class

Comment: I got that wrong a long time ago, too. ;) I'll throw in an additional quote from the [Style Guide for Python Code](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables): "Use one leading underscore only for non-public methods and instance variables."

Answer (score 0):

You have to use keyword `self` to let your class know you are using a method of itself.

You have to specify the `self` when calling the function `self.generateRandom()` and also you need to either specify when creating the function that it takes self as an argument, but since you have a static method, you can wrap it in `@staticmethod`

This is a working versio of your class `Mul`

```
class Mul:
def __init__ (self,ra_result=None,rb_result=None):
    self.ra_result = ra_result
    self.rb_result = rb_result

@staticmethod
def generateRandom():
    return np.random.randint(0,2**32), np.random.randint(0,2**32)

def Multi_test(self):
    self.ra_result,self.rb_result = self.generateRandom()
    print("expected_output (python) = ")
    print("ra=",self.ra_result,"rb=",self.rb_result," (ra*rb)=")
    return self.ra_result*self.rb_result
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to discuss why you have written your code in this way and directly talk about your error. You are getting this error because generateRandom is a method within Mul class. To refer to the other methods of the same class within a method, you should use 'self'. Additionally add static method since generateRandom doesn't use self. It would also be good if you could improve how you name variables, methods etc. The code will look like below
\

```
import numpy as np

class Mul:
    def __init__ (self,ra_result=None,rb_result=None):
        self.ra_result = ra_result
        self.rb_result = rb_result

    @staticmethod
    def generateRandom():
        return np.random.randint(0,2**32), np.random.randint(0,2**32)

    def Multi_test(self):
        self.ra_result,self.rb_result= self.generateRandom()
        print("expected_output (python) = ")
        print("ra=",self.ra_result,"rb=",self.rb_result," (ra*rb)=")
        return self.ra_result*self.rb_result
    
my_object = Mul()
my_object.Multi_test()
```